# Views - Excluding a nid screws up "More" link

Tags: views

I have a view for my news overview in which I'd like to show 5 latest items. This works perfectly. Until I want to exclude the NID i'm on right now.

I exclude the NID by using the contextual filter and exclude the current Nid.

However; this screws up the More link attached to the view. It wants to go to the excluded NID now(Because of the contextual I think).

How do I get the More link to go to my news overview(As it is without the contextual filter) but still exclude the current NID?

Comment: Build your own 'More link' in views fields using rewrite with something like: node/[nid] as href. Plenty ways to do it actually.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add "Content: Nid (Nid)" field and mark it 'Exclude from display'.
2. Now add "Global: Custom text" field, in its configuration add 'More link' into text box and then select "Output this field as a link" under REWRITE RESULTS and provide node/[nid] as a link path.